# Drupal Module: SimpleAds | Why aren't the ad statistics work?

Tags: drupal, module, content-management-system, drupal-modules

The module 'SimpleAds' is kinda new and I can't find any documentation about it. The module looks pretty straight forward but for some strange, maybe stupid, reason I can't get the ad statistics to work.

I created a text ad and an image ad, as Admin I can see the tab 'ad statistics' but when I refresh or click on it as an anonymous user or as admin no counters go up.

I checked the permissions: "Count ad impressions" and "Count ad clicks" are checked for all roles.

Doesn't somebody have more documentation or an answer for this case?

Kind regards

Comment: I posted this question also on the drupal.org site and the developper of SimpleAds told me we can be talking here about a bug.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer for this question located here: http://drupal.org/node/1436134